# How to implement PageRank alogorithm in gremlin query language without using graph computer (OLAP transaction)?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I need to implement it without using any methods or graph computer techniques since OLAP graph computer is not supported on gremlin server.

```
gremlin> g = traversal().withEmbedded(graph).withComputer()
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.withEmbedded() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph) values: [tinkergraph[vertices:360 edges:1671]]
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

I am getting this error while trying graph computer.

Comment: What have you done so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Your question is vague and likely to get closed per Stack Overflow guidelines. Perhaps edit the question to describe what you have done so far and explain why using GraphComputer is not an option as that is the easiest way to get a PageRank score in Gremlin.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a version of gremlin console older than 3.4.9. The exception only says that the withEmbedded method does not exist.

If you use version 3.4.x with x < 9, it will work with:

```
g = traversal().withGraph(graph).withComputer()
```

See: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/AnonymousTraversalSource.html